Can a dropped table be recovered from Always On availability group?
Hi I have SQL 2016 with AlwaysOn Availability. I dropped a table on the "active" node. Can I recover the table from the other node or the drop is "synched" automatically and thus the table is dropped on the other node as well?

If you do anything in the database context on the primary then those changes will be reflected on the secondary replicas. In your case, if you dropped the table, assuming the secondary replicas are connected, then the secondaries also dropped the table.

Sean already covered the answer to your specific question.
I think it's worth pointing out that, since you're using Availability Groups, you are required to have the database in the FULL recovery model, and you're likely running log backups (either that or you're rapidly headed towards running out of disk space).
With all that said, you could use those log backups (assuming you have access to them*) to restore a copy of the database to a point in time just before the table was dropped.  Then you'd have access to the lost table and its contents, and could potentially use a cross-database query to recreate and repopulate the table in the active database.
*If the log backups are going to the NUL device just to truncate the transaction log, or there isn't a complete chain of FULL / DIFFERENTIAL / LOG backups to perform the restore, then you're out of luck
